# How can I reuse a shown.bs.collapase function?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I'm using the javascript code below for a collapse that changes the colour and chevron depending if it's open or closed. I'm trying to duplicate the same behaviour but for a different button. I've tried updating the `id` and give the `.js-button` different names but that didn't seem to fully do it for me.

```
$('#accolades').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
    $(".js-chevron").addClass('fa-chevron-up').removeClass('fa-chevron-down');
    $(".js-button").addClass('button-accolades').removeClass('btn-outline-light');
  });
$('#accolades').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
    $(".js-chevron").addClass('fa-chevron-down').removeClass('fa-chevron-up');
    $(".js-button").addClass('btn-outline-light').removeClass('button-accolades');
  });
```

How can I reuse the code multiple times in a way that each time is its own instance and updates independently from the others?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it help if you wrap the two definitions in side another function? Then apply it to each item group?

```js
// Define
const applyCollapseAction = (container, chevEl, btnEl) => {
  container.on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
      chevEl.addClass('fa-chevron-up').removeClass('fa-chevron-down');
      btnEl.addClass('button-accolades').removeClass('btn-outline-light');
    });
  container.on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
      chevEl.addClass('fa-chevron-down').removeClass('fa-chevron-up');
      btnEl.addClass('btn-outline-light').removeClass('button-accolades');
  });
};

// Call
applyCollapseAction($('#accolades'), $(".js-chevron"), $(".js-button"));
applyCollapseAction($('#accolades2'), $(".js-chevron2"), $(".js-button2"));
```